# throw a descriptive error with graphql and apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, typegraphql

Consider the following class:

```js
// entity/Account.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity, Index, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm'
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql'

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Account extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => Int)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Field()
  @Column({ length: 50, unique: true })
  @Index({ unique: true })
  accountIdentifier: string

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Column({ length: 100 })
  name?: string
}
```

With it's corresponding resolver:

```js
// AccountResolver.ts
@Resolver()
export class AccountResolver {
  @Mutation(() => Account)
  async addAccount(@Arg('options', () => AccountInput) options: AccountInput) {
    try {
      // if (!options.accountIdentifier) {
      //   throw new Error(`Failed adding account: the accountIdentifier is missing`)
      // }
      return await Account.create(options).save()
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.message.includes('Cannot insert duplicate key')) {
        throw new Error(
          `Failed adding account: the account already exists. ${error}`
        )
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Failed adding account: ${error}`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Jest test file

```js
// AccountResolver.test.ts
describe('the addAccount Mutation', () => {
  it('should throw an error when the accountIdentifier is missing', async () => {
    await expect(
      client.mutate({
        mutation: gql`
        mutation {
          addAccount(
            options: {
              name: "James Bond"
              userName: "James.Bond@contoso.com"
            }
          ) {
            accountIdentifier
          }
        }
      `,
      })
    ).rejects.toThrowError('the accountIdentifier is missing')
  })
```

The field `accountIdentifier` is mandatory and should throw a descriptive error message when it's missing in the request. However, the error thrown is:

> "Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400"

What is the correct way to modify the error message? I looked at `type-graphql` with the [class-validators](https://typegraphql.com/docs/validation.html) and made sure that `validate: true` is set but it doesn't give a descriptive error.

### EDIT

After checking the graphql playground, it does show the correct error message by default. The only question remaining is how write the jest test so it can read this message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Field AccountInput.accountIdentifier of required type String! was not provided.",
```

Thank you for any help you could give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ApolloError` returned by your client wraps both the `errors` returned in the response and any network errors encountered while executing the request. The former is accessible under the `graphQLErrors` property, the latter under the `networkError` property. Instea dof using `toThrowError`, you should use `toMatchObject` instead:

```
const expectedError = {
  graphQLErrors: [{ message: 'the accountIdentifier is missing' }]
}
await expect(client.mutate(...)).rejects.toMatchObject(expectedError)
```

However, I would suggest avoiding using Apollo Client for testing. Instead, you can execute operations directly against your schema.

```
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql'
import { graphql } from 'graphql'

const schema = await buildSchema({
  resolvers: [...],
})
const query = '{ someField }'
const context = {}
const variables = {}
const { data, errors } = await graphql(schema, query, {}, context, variables)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but with your suggestion jest received is ` "graphQLErrors": Array [],` and not the visible error message in graphql playground. Updated OP with correct error message object. I'll try to convert my code to not use `apollo-client` per your suggestion.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Sorry, I forgot to mention that the other issue here is that the query you're sending is actually invalid (that's what the 400 status indicates). You can inspect the value of the `networkError` property on the error object to determine the cause.

Comment: Last question: is there an advantage of not using `apollo-client`? Why did you suggest that?

Comment: If you have a GraphQL API, what you want to test is the response from that API, not necessarily how any one client consumes that response.

Comment: True! And using `graphql` directly is more clean too. Just one issue remaining, matching my jest expectation to this error object ` [GraphQLError: Field AccountInput.accountIdentifier of required type String! was not provided.],`. Can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify` to inspect the error object's properties.